# Teamviz symbolic link

Tags: c++, std, symlink, stdstring

Lately I've downloaded TeamViz (ex-Pomodoro app). It's not installable, so I just run executable file ./Teamviz and it works.
I want it to be ran from the terminal. So what I do

```
sudo mv TeamViz /opt
sudo ln -s /opt/TeamViz/TeamViz /usr/bin/teamviz
```

When i type `teamviz` I get this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Yet If I run it by ./TeamViz, everything goes well.

What do I do wrong and how to fix it (me or problem)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

TeamViz is most likely trying to find information relating to running it. In this case it's looking (most likely) in `/usr/bin` for TeamViz related files.

The proper way to launch it is a stub-script, rather than a symlink e.g. something like:

```
#!/bin/bash -p
exec /opt/TeamViz/TeamViz "$@"
```

Placed as the executable `/usr/bin/TeamViz`.

It's not uncommon to have this issue with applications that 'self host'.

Typically the app uses `dirname(argv[0])` to determine it's running directory rather than `dirname(realpath(argv[0]))`, and so misdetects it's launch directory as where the symbolic link is rather than where the real binary is located. An example of this would look like:

```
$ cat for_reals.c 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char realdest[1024];

    realpath(argv[0], realdest);

    printf("%s\n", realdest);
    return 0;
}
$ make for_reals
cc     for_reals.c   -o for_reals
$ ./for_reals 
/Users/petesh/Development/experiments/for_reals/for_reals
$ ln -fs for_reals charlie
$ ./charlie
/Users/petesh/Development/experiments/for_reals/for_reals
```